# List cannot be cast to my class which extend List. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two classes.

```
class QuestionList : ArrayList<QuestionItem>()

data class QuestionItem(
        val id: Int,
        val order: Int,
        val header: String,
       
)
```

When i filtered questionList object, it return array list of questionItem.

```
var questionList = gson.fromJson(str, QuestionList::class.java)
val filteredQuestionList = questionList.filter { it.lesson_id == id } as QuestionList // error here. cannot be cast
```

I want to cast ArrayList to QuestionList. but i take error that list cannot be cast to QuestionList.
I have list of QuestionItem but i need QuestionList object. How to solved this problem, by casting or using another way ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `filter` method is not aware of your `QuestionList` class, so it returns a *new* filtered `List<QuestionItem>` that is not a `QuestionList`.

To solve the problem, assuming the `QuestionList` class really is an empty subclass, you could simply use `List<QuestionItem>` wherever you're currently using `QuestionList` (except for the Gson call), or call `.toMutableList()` if you need the result to be mutable.